# Error viewing csproj property pages in VisualStudio2005

Tags: visual-studio

When I goto view the property page for my CSharp test application I get the following error.

"An error occurred trying to load the page. COM object that has been seperated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

The only thing that seems to fix it is rebooting my PC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by a 'rogue' add-in.

Try disabling them all, and then re-enabling them checking for the error - so that you can narrow down the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft Style Cop was causing the issue.

It was not registered as an Add-in, but was integrated into VS2005 on some deeper level.